# echarts4r: liquid fill color

Tags: r, data-visualization

How can I change the colors in [e_liquid](http://echarts4r.john-coene.com/reference/e_liquid.html?q=e%20_%20liquid#examples)?  Here is my latest attempt:

```
liquid <- data.frame(val = c(0.2, 0.2), 
                     col = c("red", "red"))

liquid %>% 
  e_charts() %>% 
  e_liquid(serie = val, color = col)
```

You can see it isn't red.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, that *was* a bug.

Reinstall `devtools::install_github("JohnCoene/echarts4r")` Then rerun

```
library(echarts4r)

liquid <- data.frame(val = c(0.2, 0.3), 
                     col = c("red", "blue"))

liquid %>% 
    e_charts() %>% 
    e_liquid(serie = val, color = col)
```

[image]